# Docker permissions are different when running on CodeBuild

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

I am using `ruby:2.5.1-alpine` for my application's container image. When I run `make release` locally, which runs the following commands:

```
docker-compose build --pull release
docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit test
```

The test stage runs the migrations, linter and specs. It runs without an issues. When I run the same exact command on CodeBuild which is using a `aws/codebuild/ruby:2.5.1` as the host environment I get the following error:

```
Running RuboCop...
Inspecting 82 files
.................................................................................W
 Offenses:
 bin/console:1:1: W: Lint/ScriptPermission: Script file console doesn't have execute permission.
```

I checked the git permissions and everything looks kosher:

```
edit [...master ] git ls-tree HEAD bin/
100755 blob ad9a02fe6ed489beb105295de771cab5fa87a6af    bin/console
100755 blob 9d87e9579b9c16c42d65301e8540888e044ba25d    bin/run
100755 blob cf5febb7c6dd34aebdb862792fa147d06a9c5764    bin/setup
edit [...master ]
```

I added a debug statement to see what the permissions are at the time of the tests running and here is where it diverges.

Locally I get:

```
test_1_4d039799a73c | File permissions for bin/console are 
#<File::Stat ino=10432530, **mode=0100755**, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000,...>
```

And On the CodeBuild server I get:

```
File permissions for bin/console are 
#<File::Stat  ino=525319, **mode=0100666**, nlink=1, uid=0, gid=0, ...>
```

As I pasted the above I also noticed that the UID and the GID are different. So it looks like the permissions are not being set correctly:

```
RUN addgroup -g 1000 app && adduser -u 1000 -G app -D app
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_ROOT

WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
```

This was part of the issue:

https://forums.docker.com/t/not-able-to-change-permissions-for-files-and-folders-created-on-mounted-volumes/45769

After removing the volume for the stage that runs on CodeBuild the mid and gig are correct but the permissions themselves are still off.

```
 ·[36mcodebuild_1 |·[0m File permissions for bin/console are 
 #<File::Stat ino=2755035, mode=0100666, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000...>
```

Not sure how to go about debugging this.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm running into a similar issue when trying to mount a locally created directory through docker compose and get denied permission to write to it from the container

Comment: @Paul unfortunately no. The file was not critical to my application so I wound up removing it. It is driving me crazy so if you do find an answer can you please post it here if you don;'t mind.

Comment: I myself found a work around and ended up copying all the files I needed from the container after the job had finished running and the container was stopped using [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/). Not sure that's something that would solve your problem too